# C Mysterious Overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Why does this code output -32768 and not 32768? Looks like an overflow but I cannot figure out where.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    buffer[0] = 0x80;
    buffer[1] = 0x00;
    int address = (buffer[0]<<8) | (buffer[1]);
    printf("%d\n", address); //outputs -32768
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because buffer[0] is -128

Comment: oh wow that should be unsigned shouldnt it

Comment: an "int" is a signed number.  If the high order bit is set in a signed integer it signifies it is negative.   Perhaps you should google "two's complement".

Comment: And your "char *buffer" should be "unsigned char *buffer"....

Comment: it is **-32768** because when we do **-128<<8** it becomes -32768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your compiler `char` is signed.

On your compiler, `0x80` is converted to `-0x80` to fit in a signed `char`.

So `buffer[0]` holds -128, and `((-128)<<8) | (0)` evaluates to -32768.

Comment: `(-128)<<8` evaluates to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible ways that this code can execute.

- Either `char` is unsigned on your compiler. Then the expression will get evaluated as `0x80<<8 | 0x00` which gives `0x8000`. If this fits inside an `int` on your system, the result will be 32768. Otherwise it will get converted to a signed format in some implementation-defined way. On a two's complement computer you will likely get the result -32768.
- Or `char` is signed on your compiler. Then `0x80` can't fit inside it, but gets converted to a negative number in some implementation-defined way. On a two's complement computer it will likely get the value -128. You then left shift this negative value - this invokes *undefined behavior* (source: C11 6.5.7/4). This in turn could cause anything to happen: your program could crash or print nonsense, or there could be some specific non-standard behavior on your compiler such as treating the result as -32768.

The key here is that you shouldn't write code like this, which relies on numerous forms of poorly specified behavior. That's bad practice. The reason why you end up with this because you are using the native, primitive data types of C like `char` and `int`, which are poorly specified and therefore dangerous to use for bit manipulations.

Your code should be fixed into something safe, that will give a deterministic result no matter system or compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t *buffer = malloc( sizeof(uint8_t[2]) );
    buffer[0] = 0x80;
    buffer[1] = 0x00;
    uint16_t address = ((uint16_t)buffer[0]<<8) | (buffer[1]);
    printf("%" PRIu16 "\n", address);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```